# Zebra DataWedge, how to trigger a Scan from code?

Tags: android, datawedge, zebra-scanners

We have a Zebra Android device (MC33X) & I'm able to scan through the hardware button & is there a way to scan through click of a button on the screen?

Also is there a provision to Auto scan or Continuous scan?

Comment: [Soft Scan trigger](https://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/13-0/guide/api/softscantrigger/).